# UITextField autocapitalizationType UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters not working on device

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, xcode4.6.3

You can set the autocapitalizationType property of a UITextField so all input is in upper case. I find that does work fine on the simulator (when actually tapping the simulator's keypad, not the Mac's keyboard), but not on the device? Everything stays lowercase.

In the UICatalog demo I added to the textFieldNormal method:

```
textFieldNormal.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```

Added a delegate too, to display the actual autocapitalizationType for the UITextField:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog( @"textField.autocapitalizationType=%d", textField.autocapitalizationType );
}
```

It will properly display 3 (=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters), but anything you tap remains lowercase. What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently this is a device general settings issue: Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Auto-Capitalization must be ON to honour the setting of textField.autocapitalizationType to all upper case, else setting the property is ignored, apparently. If I switch it on everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this the the textfield delegate:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (range.length == 0) { // not deleting , but adding a char        
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:[string uppercaseString]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This works only if you try to insert a symbol at the end of the text.
Should you want to play with the text in the middle you could play with

> range.location

and also you will need to play with the cursor positioning as it will go at the end every time...

I hope this helps someone.