# Can I get a UITextField to honor the users Auto-Capitalization setting in Settings/General/Keyboard?

Tags: ios

I know I can set UITextField capitalization to sentences to have the first letter type capitalized, but I can I instead have it be based on the users Auto-Capitalization setting in Settings/General/Keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The user can only enable or disable auto capitalization, and if it's set to no, I guess your autocapitalization property has no effect, I guess.

So basically no, there is no way to map the boolean to the autocapitalization enum.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is done by default. If the user has Auto-capitalization in setting's set to the "off" state then your UITextField capitalization state will just be ignored by the device. 
Reference: [UITextField autocapitalizationType UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17879752/2057171)